# Apply Custom Page Layout not possible / LWR Template

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, lightning-community, community-builder, digital-experience

I'm building a digital experience site on the new LWR template. Therefore I'm trying to apply a custom page layout - see relevant xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="customPageLayout">
    <apiVersion>51.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>Your Custom Page Layout</masterLabel>
    <description>A custom layout</description>
    <targets>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page_Layout</target>  
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

But - the template doesn't show up / I can't apply it to the page. Does anyone have an idea, what I did wrong? I also checked the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.exp_cloud_lwr.meta/exp_cloud_lwr/get_started_layout.htm) but couldn't find an answer.

[image]

Thank you for your help!
Maserick

Comment: Can you try approach in https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=inconsistent-behavior-when-changing-the-layout-for-a-page-variation-when-the-page-uses-flexible-layout&Id=a1p4V000001TvJ1

Comment: done @Swetha - thank you for the tipp.

Comment: Question is: How do I create a none Flexible Layout page?

Comment: Hi, there is the possibility to build non-flex layouts. Check out this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pcFfTtL4hzU), which is a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour you are seeing is related to this [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=inconsistent-behavior-when-changing-the-layout-for-a-page-variation-when-the-page-uses-flexible-layout&Id=a1p4V000001TvJ1) according to which

> When accessing the page properties in Experience Builder of the
> variation, the option to change the layout is greyed out. However, you
> can change the layout if you first start from the page properties of a
> non-flexible layout variation and switch to the flexible page
> variation.

The intended restriction is to prevent the change of the layout if the previous layout type is Flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an known issue - see here https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=inconsistent-behavior-when-changing-the-layout-for-a-page-variation-when-the-page-uses-flexible-layout&Id=a1p4V000001TvJ1

Thank you @swetha for the tipp!

Comment: Thanks for confirming :) As links tend to expire over time, copying details of KI as an answer so it might help others too.

Comment: This is really not an answer because in LWR it seems that you can only have flexible layout. There is no other option.